# Fully written word (not abbreviated) when word first occurs in every chapter

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

I use the glossaries package for acronyms with default settings. Now I need that abbreviated words are fully written when they first occurs in the next chapter and not only when they first occurs. But I need only one list of abbreviations. Is there a simple solution for that?

```
\documentclass[BCOR=10mm,DIV=11]
{scrreprt}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{scrlayer}
\KOMAoptions{onpsinit=\linespread{1}\selectfont}
\usepackage[
    automark,                               %% Kapitelangaben in Kopfzeile automatisch erstellen
    headsepline, 
    footsepline, 
    plainheadsepline, 
    plainfootsepline,
]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\usepackage[
xindy,
%nonumberlist,                              %% Keine Seitenzahlen anzeigen
acronym,                                    %% Ein Abkürzungsverzeichnis erstellen
toc,                                        %% Einträge im Inhaltsverzeichnis
]
{glossaries}

%Den Punkt am Ende jeder Beschreibung bei Glossaries deaktivieren
\renewcommand*{\glspostdescription}{ (verwendet auf Seite }
\newcommand*{\postpagelist}{)}

%Eigener Style für Glossaries
\newglossarystyle{mystyle}{%
 \setglossarystyle{list}%
 \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
 {\begin{description}[\setleftmargin{.2\hsize}]}%
 {\end{description}}%
 \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%
   \item[\glsentryitem{##1}%
         \glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}}]
      \glossentrydesc{##1}\glspostdescription\space ##2\postpagelist}%
}

\newacronym[description={\glslink{CBIR}{Content Based Image Retrieval}}]{CBIR}{CBIR}{Content Based Image Retrieval}

\setkomafont{captionlabel}{\bfseries}           %% Label-Bildunterschrift fett
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\small}          %% Kopfzeile klein

\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\ihead[]{}
\chead[]{}
\ohead[\headmark]{\headmark}

\ifoot[]{}
\cfoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
\ofoot[]{}

\AfterTOCHead{\singlespacing}
\onehalfspacing
\KOMAoptions{DIV=last}

\begin{document}

\title{Titel}
\author{1}

\begin{spacing}{1}
\maketitle
\end{spacing}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{1}
\blindtext
\gls{CBIR}
\blindtext
\gls{CBIR}
\chapter{2}
\blindtext
\gls{CBIR}
\blindtext
\gls{CBIR}

\renewcommand{\glossarypostamble}{\protect\par\vspace{5ex}\noindent\textbf{Anmerkung: }Alle im Text verwendeten Abkürzungen sind im Abkürzungsverzeichnis aufgeführt. Bei der ersten Verwendung wurden diese ausgeschrieben und anschließend die zugehörige Abkürzung in Klammern angefügt. Bei einer erneuten Verwendung des Begriffs wurde nur die Abkürzung benutzt. Geläufige Abkürzungen und Firmennamen sind nicht aufgeführt.}
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype, style=mystyle]
\end{document}
```

Comment: you can add a hook to each `\chapter` unsetting the used flag of each acronym.

Comment: Okay, http://ctan.mackichan.com/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.pdf chapter 4. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since it's a simple hook, I would use `xpatch` for this.

[image]

```
\documentclass[BCOR=10mm,DIV=11]
{scrreprt}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{scrlayer}
\KOMAoptions{onpsinit=\linespread{1}\selectfont}
\usepackage[
    automark,                               %% Kapitelangaben in Kopfzeile automatisch erstellen
    headsepline, 
    footsepline, 
    plainheadsepline, 
    plainfootsepline,
]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\usepackage[
xindy,
%nonumberlist,                              %% Keine Seitenzahlen anzeigen
acronym,                                    %% Ein Abkürzungsverzeichnis erstellen
toc,                                        %% Einträge im Inhaltsverzeichnis
]
{glossaries}

%Den Punkt am Ende jeder Beschreibung bei Glossaries deaktivieren
\renewcommand*{\glspostdescription}{ (verwendet auf Seite }
\newcommand*{\postpagelist}{)}

%Eigener Style für Glossaries
\newglossarystyle{mystyle}{%
 \setglossarystyle{list}%
 \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
 {\begin{description}[\setleftmargin{.2\hsize}]}%
 {\end{description}}%
 \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%
   \item[\glsentryitem{##1}%
         \glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}}]
      \glossentrydesc{##1}\glspostdescription\space ##2\postpagelist}%
}

\newacronym[description={\glslink{CBIR}{Content Based Image Retrieval}}]{CBIR}{CBIR}{Content Based Image Retrieval}

\setkomafont{captionlabel}{\bfseries}           %% Label-Bildunterschrift fett
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\small}          %% Kopfzeile klein

\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\ihead[]{}
\chead[]{}
\ohead[\headmark]{\headmark}

\ifoot[]{}
\cfoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
\ofoot[]{}

\AfterTOCHead{\singlespacing}
\onehalfspacing
\KOMAoptions{DIV=last}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpretocmd{\chapter}{\glsresetall}{}{}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\chapter{One}
\blindtext
\textcolor{red}{\bfseries\gls{CBIR}}
\blindtext
\textcolor{red}{\bfseries\gls{CBIR}}
\chapter{Two}
\blindtext
\textcolor{red}{\bfseries\gls{CBIR}}
\blindtext
\textcolor{red}{\bfseries\gls{CBIR}}

\renewcommand{\glossarypostamble}{\protect\par\vspace{5ex}\noindent\textbf{Anmerkung: }Alle im Text verwendeten Abkürzungen sind im Abkürzungsverzeichnis aufgeführt. Bei der ersten Verwendung wurden diese ausgeschrieben und anschließend die zugehörige Abkürzung in Klammern angefügt. Bei einer erneuten Verwendung des Begriffs wurde nur die Abkürzung benutzt. Geläufige Abkürzungen und Firmennamen sind nicht aufgeführt.}
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype, style=mystyle]
\end{document}
```